# Confusion about the notation used for the chain complex of a torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, definition, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology in a section talking about finitely based chain complexes; I have come across this page and am confused by some of the notation and words.

$(1)$ What is the adequate subcomplex here, are they saying the identified torus of the square is the adequate subcomplex?

$(2)$ I understand that chains in a complex $E_*$ are the elements of each $E_q$, but what does $E_2=\langle P \rangle$ mean?  What does $E_1=\langle a \rangle \oplus \langle b \rangle$ mean?

$(3)$  And how do these differentiations (boundary operator) imply the bottom results?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what's meant by 'adequate subcomplex'. The notation $\langle P \rangle$ here means the free abelian group generated by $P$, that is $\langle P \rangle = \{ nP \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ where elements are formal sums of the element $P$. The boundary operator of $P$ for instance is given by reading the edges with orientation as you move around the face $P$ counter-clockwise starting from the top right of the square. All of this is explained on the [wikipedia page for simplicial homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_homology).

Comment: @DanRust A subcomplex $E_*'$ of a chain complex $E_*$ is adequate if, for all $q \gt 0$:  **Condition 1**.  If $z \in Z_q$ then there exists $z' \in Z_q'$ with $z-z' \in B_q$.  **Condition 2**.  If $z' \in Z'_q$ and $z' = \partial c$ for some $c in E_{q+1}$, then there exists $c' \in E'_{q+1}$ with $z' = \partial c'$

Comment: @DanRust What is a formal sum of $P$?  And if $\partial_2 : E_2 \rightarrow E_1$ by $\partial(\langle p_0, p_1, p_2 \rangle) = \sum_{i=0}^2(-1)^i \langle p_0, \dots \tilde p_i, \dots p_2 \rangle$, how can this be used since there's no $2$-simplexes in this square or the torus?